# como le agrego la ruta al tocar la notificacion push de firebase con php

Tags: php, firebase

quisiera saber como le agrego la ruta al pulsar la notificacion push que envie por **PHP** con **firebase**, quiero que al pulsarla o me **envié a un enlace** o una **activity** de mi app android, gracias, dejo el fracmento de codigo como me anda funcionando actualmente.

```
      $headers = array(
      'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
      'Content-Type:application/json'
  );
  $fields = array('to'=>$deviceToken,
      'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message,'image'=>$img));
```

Comment: ¿Estás usando `curl_exec()` para enviar la petición o alguna biblioteca de funciones de firebase? ¿Podrías compartir su nombre, versión, y también el ciclo completo y método de llamada en tu código? Es decir, si usas `curl_exec()` comparte la creación con `curl_init()`, las opciones `curl_setopt()` y cómo almacenas el resultado de `curl_exec()`. Si usaste una biblioteca de funciones indica si usaste composer para instalarla o si te la descargaste comprimida (en ese caso comparte también el `require` que has usado).

Comment: hola buenas noches, si claro estoy usando lo anteriormente nombrado por usted, y aún así no me envía ni icono ni tuya al pulsar la notificación ni menos URL, ayer investigue y al parecer el servicio de firebase tiene actualmente esa limitación ya que es de servicio público.